# Table and condition to display selection on not

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use `Angular 16`
In a table, I need to display a column with selection but this column must be displayed only if a specific condition is true.

Edit

By selection, i mean
material-table has selection feature that lets users to select multiple rows.

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection

I would like to display it if a certain condition is true
https://stackblitz.com/angular/lrpjroljdly?embed=1&file=app/table-selection-example.html

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with `[hidden]`. for example here user can see `owner` column only if the user is admin:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Username</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.userName}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="owner" >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [hidden] = "this.loginService.getCookie('username')!='admin'">Owner</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [hidden] = "this.loginService.getCookie('username')!='admin'"> {{userName}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mat-table you can change the "displayedColumns" array

You can change the variable

```
columnsNecesary=['one','two']
columnsAll=['one','two','optional']
displayedColumns=this.columnsNecesary

condition=true;

//in any place
this.displayedColumns=condition?columsAll:columnsNecesary
```

Or use the own .html

e.g.

```
necesaryColumns=['one','two']
optionalColumns=['optional']
conditional=true;

<tr mat-header-row 
    *matHeaderRowDef="condition?[...necesaryColumns,...optionalColumns]:
                                 necesaryColumns">
</tr>
```